# SQL Select latest record for employee if value is "Selected"

Tags: sql

I have a "status history" table that contains a list of employee's employment statuses. What I would like to do is grab a list of each employees latest record if and only if their status value is "Up To Date".

So far, this is the query I have with pseudo code

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP.EmployeeRecords
WHERE (THE LATEST STATUS RECORD) StatusValue = 'Up To Date'
```

Comment: Add table definition, some sample table data and expected result!

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite poorly formed.  You should have sample data and desired layouts, as well as tagging the question with the database you are using.

Guessing at the structure of data, here is with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM EMP.EmployeeRecords e
WHERE e.statusdate = (select max(e2.statusdate) 
                      from emp.EmployeeRecords e2
                      where e2.employeeid = e.employeeid
                     ) and
      e.StatusValue = 'Up To Date';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the MAX() function John. Take a look at the following for the definition:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx

Taking some assumptions into account:

Lets say that you have a `EmployeeRecordsID` on the `EMP.EmployeeRecords` table which is an auto-incrementing identity column as well as an `EmployeeName` to differentiate the different employees; to get the latest record where the `StatusValue = 'Up To Date'` you would do something like the following

```
select 
  LatestID = MAX(EmployeeRecordsID)
  , EmployeeName
from EMP.EmployeeRecords
where StatusValue = 'Up To Date'
group by EmployeeName
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Should have been a comment instead.